# AutoIt ControlSend() function occasionally replaces hyphens with underscores

Tags: automation, autoit

I'm using an AutoIt script to automate interaction with a GUI, and part of the process involves using the [ControlSend()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm) function to place a file path into a combo box.  The majority of the time, the process works properly, but occasionally ( ~ 1/50 calls to the function? ) a single hyphen in the filepath is replaced with an underscore.  The script is to be run unsupervised for bulk data processing, and such an error typically results in a forced-focus popup that screams "The file could not be found!" and halts further processing.

Unfortunately, due to the character limit of the combo box, I cannot supply all 16 arguments with a single call, and I am forced to load each of the images individually using the following for-loop:

```
;Iterate through each command line argument (file path)
For $i = 1 To $CmdLine[0]
    ;click the "Disk" Button to load an image from disk
    ControlClick("Assemble HDR Image", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Disk; Instance:1]")
    ;Give the dialogue time to open before entering text
    Sleep(1000)
    ;Send a single file path to the combo box
    ControlSend("Open", "" , "Edit1", $CmdLine[$i])
    ;"Press Enter" to load the image
    Send("{ENTER}")
Next
```

In an errant run, the file path

```
C:\my\file\path\hdr_2016-04-22T080033_00_rgb
                        ^Hyphen
```

is converted to

```
C:\my\file\path\hdr_2016_04-22T080033_00_rgb
                        ^Underscore
```

Due to the existence of both hyphens and underscores in the file name, it is difficult to perform a programmatic correction (e.g. replace all underscores with hyphens).

What can be done to correct or prevent such an error?

---

This is both my first attempt at GUI automation and my first question on SO, and I apologize for my lack of experience, poor wording, or deviations from StackOverflow convention.

Comment: Did you press shift while the script was running? You might use `BlockInput(...)` but with care to prevent this. Did you check with `ConsoleWrite(...)` if the desired output data is the very same like the input data? You might fiddle with the SendKeyDelay Options to have it processed faster, but the reason for this strange behavior isn't obvious... Or you might use the clipboard and `Send("^v")` to have the complete file path inserted at once. Or just use `ControlSetText` instead of `ControlSend`.

Comment: @Samoth Excellent!  Using ControlSetText appears to fix the problem.  While I'm still curious as to why the problem occurred, this gets the job done.  I'd like to accept this as the answer and will do so if you move it to the answers category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ControlSetText` instead of `ControlSend` as it will set the complete Text at once and won't allow other keystrokes (like Shift) to interfere with the many virtual keystrokes that the Send-function fires.

Answer (score 1):

If the hyphen is the problem and you need to replace it, you can do so:

```
#include <File.au3>

; your path
$sPath = 'C:\my\file\path'

; get all files from this path
$aFiles = _FileListToArray($sPath, '*', 1)

; if all your files looks like that (with or without hyphen), you can work with "StringRegExpReplace"
; 'hdr_2016-04-22T080033_00_rgb'

$sPattern = '(\D+\d{4})(.)(.+)'
; it means:
; 1st group: (\D+\d{4})
;    \D+    one or more non-digit, i.e. "hdr_"
;    \d{4}  digit 4-times, i.e. "2016"
; 2nd group: (.)
;    .      any character, hyphen, underscore or other, only one character, i.e. "~"
; 3rd group: (.+)
;    .      any character, one or more times, i.e. "22T080033_00_rgb"

; now you change the filename for all cases, where this pattern matches
Local $sTmpName
For $i = 1 To $aFiles[0]
    ; check for pattern match
    If StringRegExp($aFiles[$i]) Then
        ; replace the 2nd group with underscore
        $sTmpName = StringRegExpReplace($aFiles[$i], $sPattern, '\1_\3')
        FileMove($sPath & '\' & $aFiles[$i], $sPath  & '\' & $sTmpName)
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I actually didn't know about regex grouping (backreferences?) and replacement of certain parts of a pattern.  It looks like the regex method works well for replacing / standardizing the input, but it appears that the problem is related to correctly outputting information.